# SAP Spartacus Create login popup

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I need to create registration/login popup.

1. The header component is on all pages.
2. I have login button in header.
3. I have page /login/register with a slot BodyContentSlot-register
   I don’t know how many components can be added to BodyContentSlot-register, but I need to click on the icon in the header to show the registration form in a modal window without going to the registration page. And show in a modal window all the components of this slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve directly what you've described:

1. In the modal:
2. you need to make a call using CMS service to get page data (that calls backend for CMS page data) OR get the data if you've loaded it before (as an optimizaiton only)
3. display the slot's content you want to show, i.e. using `cx-page-slot` component statically in your modal and passing the `position` as an input
4. The tricky part is that this component gets from CmsService the slots of the *current page*, i.e. cart page (based on routing /cart), but not the *page data* you've loaded programatically in your modal. So you need to customize CmsService to return you the CMS data for specific slot of given page (register), even if it's not a part of *current page* data.

Comment: I try this in my component
this.store.select(CmsSelectors.getPageData({id: '/login', type: PageType.CONTENT_PAGE})).subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
    });
It's work on login page, but not wort on another page(

Comment: This code works!!!
this.cmsService.getPage({id: '/login', type: PageType.CONTENT_PAGE}).subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
    });

Comment: Great! Please mind that if you use personalization (you display or not some CMS components for different users, i.e. a personalized banner for part of users on the registration page), then you should consider calling `CmsService.getPage()` with a flag `force: true` to (re)load page data on each attempt to display a modal. Otherwise you'll see the same components as the ones loaded at the first time.... which in case of no personalization is 100% correct.